# aws cli broken? Get "string indices must be integers"

Tags: python, pip, homebrew, aws-cli

For some reason since recently installing awscli I can't seem to do anything I just keep getting `string indices must be integers`

```
> aws s3 ls s3://foo

string indices must be integers
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling with brew and pip.

Comment: Can you post the output of `aws --version`?

Comment: OK I tried the third way of installing aws (using the zip) then when I run `aws --version` I get `aws-cli/1.10.0 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/15.3.0 botocore/1.3.22`

Comment: Odd -- I've got the same environment, but your command works for me. Is it possible that your AWS API keys or environment variables are misconfigured?

Comment: @JulesMazur Irrelevant, it should say something like "you need to configure aws".  Try uninstalling awscli and reinstalling, I'm convinced they just broke it today!

Comment: OMG, @JulesMazur your right, running `aws configure` and setting the aws key and secret fixed it. WTF kind of s*** error reporting is that!!!

Comment: good point. I had actually tried the command first with 1.9.20, which also worked. I then installed 1.10.0 via brew.

Answer (score 2):

This is a horrible bug in the awscli error reporting.  You need to first run `aws configure`